# Show derivative on a plot line with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I want to show a triangle on a line plot from matplotlib describing the derivative with some description text or plain value/name.

Let's say I'm plotting a very simple line:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = (1, 3, 7, 10)
y = (1, 3, 7, 10)

plt.plot(x, y, '-o', mfc='none')
# plt.show_derivative(x=x[1], y=y[1], name='$\gamma$')  # <- What I want
plt.show()
```

And I want to explicitely show the derivative like this:

[Wished result in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igrIk.png)

[another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdsgY.jpg)

Is there a quick function or way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cloud try something like this:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plotDerivative(x1, x2, y1, y2, name):
    triangle = plt.Polygon([[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x2, y1]], color='black', alpha=1, fill=False)
    plt.gca().add_patch(triangle)
    plt.text(x2 ,y1 , name, fontsize=20)


x = (1, 3, 7, 10)
y = (1, 3, 7, 10)

plt.plot(x, y, '-o', mfc='none')
plotDerivative(x[1] + x[1]/2, x[2]-x[1]/2, y[1]+y[1]/2, y[2]-y[1]/2, '$\gamma$')
plt.show()
```

There is maybe a better way, but it works

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAHHA.png)

Comment: Good enough for me, thank you!